# Can text overflow ellipsis target one element?

Tags: css, mobile-safari

I'm trying to shorten a URL with text overflow ellipsis to keep things short in Mobile Safari.

Here is my code and [page](http://bit.ly/kDJRlH).

```
dd a {
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:20px;
    background:red; /* for debugging */
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `"target one element"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right start, the only problem is the rules aren't all being applied because a tags are inline by default and need to be block-level. Adding "display: block" to your CSS will do the trick and, luckily, because of the way you're styling your dds, it won't change your layout. Also, nix the 20px width :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little hard to parse, but basically yes.  The CSS selector could be for just one element.  The easiest way would be to give the element an id, like `id="mythingie"`
and have the selector use that.

```
#mythingie {
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:20px;
    background:red; /* for debugging */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, check out the new css3 selectors and you'll quickly be able to select whatever element you want :)

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors